# Everything is cool if you bend to my rules

Tags: riddle

This was suggested to me by a friend.

> I give, I take
>   Not known to make a mistake
>   Like it or not, I call the shots
>   To complete your task,
>   Questions I must ask.
>   For a start, prove who you are
>   Or you won't go far
>   Options I set and choices you select
>   What do you want? Come on, answer my prompts!
>   A bad selection, and you'll suffer a rejection
>   Hey, don't get edgy
>   If you want to achieve your goal early
>   Everything is cool
>   If you bend to my rules
>   Look, you have just finished
>   Will you take that small sheet?
>   Someday, who knows when
>   We'll meet and do it again

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it an

> ATM (automatic teller machine)?

I give, I take

> You can withdraw, you can pay-in

Not known to make a mistake

> I would hope so, although there have been exceptions

Like it or not, I call the shots

> It's my money, but it's up to the machine to give me some

To complete your task,
Questions I must ask.
For a start, prove who you are
Or you won't go far

> Go through the security or you won't go far

Options I set and choices you select

> Multiple choices

What do you want? Come on, answer my prompts!

> Make the selection what you want to do

A bad selection, and you'll suffer a rejection

> You make a mistake, it spits out the card (or worse - swallows it)

Hey, don't get edgy
If you want to achieve your goal early

> No point in arguing with a machine

Everything is cool
If you bend to my rules

> It's all cool if you follow the rules

Look, you have just finished
Will you take that small sheet?

> Do you need a receipt, sir?

Someday, who knows when
We'll meet and do it again

> Quite likely

Comment: Spoilers! (I don't know how to spoiler comments).


The small sheet that you take is more fittingly the money you withdraw, or even a receipt, rather than an advice slip

Comment: Nice! Just edited one line which did not fit.